# Safe dynamically created views in linearLayout when app is killed

Tags: java, android, xml

Here is the problem and what goes with it:

**The app:**
My little app lets the user tipe in some text into an editText, and onClick he can display it as a checkBox with text in a linearLayout below.

**Initial Situation:**
I saved the variables using the onSaveInstanceState()- and the onRestoreInstanceState() methods and it works perfectly when just the orientation changes, but if the app gets quitted and completely new opened...

**Question:**
How do I safe the checkBoxes/LinealLayout, so that the list doesn't get resetted everytime the user closes and reopens the app?

**The Java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("btn_check_holo_light", "drawable", "android");
    int i;
    public CheckBox[] checkBox;
    public CheckBox[] checker;
    public String speicher;
    public String bringer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setId(R.id.id);
        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        clear = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.delete);
        parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        scroller = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroller);

    }


    public void deleteAllBoxes() {

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "List cleared", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        layout.removeAllViews();
        editText.setText("");
        checkBox = null;
        checker = null;
        content.clear();


        brücke.clear();
        speicher = null;
        bringer = null;
        i = 0;
    }
}
```

**The app:**

[image]

Comment: feel free to use one of the android's storage options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save it in one of Android's persistent storage options: in your case `SharedPreferences` will probably work nicely.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Update the shared preferences when the checkboxes are modified, and read and initialize the checkboxes with the values in the shared preferences in your activity's `onCreate`.